# Hard reset Samsung NX300

Tags: firmware, samsung

Is it possible to hard/factory reset Samsung NX300? I tried [this](http://seventrumpet.com/how-to-reset-recover-and-protect-your-photos-on-samsung-nx300/) guide, which is complete nonsense.

Comment: I know there is an option in the Settings, however, it does not reset EVERYTHING.

Comment: In what way is it complete nonsense?  I take it you followed all the steps and it didn't reset something.  What?

Comment: There is no "Power" button on this camera, therefore point 2 in "HOW TO HARD RESET SAMSUNG NX300" is invalid.

Comment: No power switch?  Top of the camera, that says on/off?

Comment: Power switch and power button are two different things. And yes, I tried switching it on and holding for 15 seconds.

Comment: Ok, well if taking the battery out and using the reset menu didn't work (manual says: "Reset the setup menu and shooting options to the factory defaults. (Date, time, language, and video output settings
do not change.) " then I guess, again, what is the setting or problem you are having?  What isn't being reset by the menu that is causing you grief?

Comment: "Date, time, language, and video output settings do not change" - I want a complete factory reset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The manual doesn't mention a procedure for doing a hard reset.  The menu option leaves the date, time, language and video output settings alone.  So you can use the menu option, and then change the date/time, language separately, or you can remove the battery for a period of time and hope for the best.